# Update selected row values in DataGridView through textbox using LINQ C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have a form. Which contains 2 tab.

1. First Tab is for instance `Team1` info, where you can select player from `datagridview`. Selected player's info will populate in designated `textboxes`.
2. In tab 2 `Team2`, and exactly same concept.

I do use same exactly code to update Team 1(Tab1) player's info,and I works. But not for Team 2(Tab 2) player's.

This is screen shot of my code[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Team 1

```
 private void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Local Variable
        int barID = 0;


        if (team1DataGridView.CurrentRow != null)
        {   
            //Get row index
            int rowIndex = team1DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index;

            //Pass to local Variable
            barID = Convert.ToInt32(team1DataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
        }

        var updatePlayers = (from p in _dbContext.barcelonaTeams
            where p.ID == barID
            select p).SingleOrDefault();

        if (updatePlayers != null)
        {
            updatePlayers.LastName = lastNameTextBox.Text;
            updatePlayers.FirstName = firstNameTextBox.Text;
            updatePlayers.Phone = cellNumberTextBox.Text;
            updatePlayers.PlayersPosition = playerPositionComboBox.Text;
        }

        try
        {
          //Submit Changes
           _dbContext.SubmitChanges();

            //Refresh datagridview'
            team1DataGridView.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //Display an error message
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

Team 2

```
private void mUpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Local variable
        int barID = 0;


        if (team2DataGridView.CurrentRow != null)
        {
            //Get row index
            int rowIndex = team2DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index;

            //Pass to local Variable
            barID = Convert.ToInt32(team2DataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
        }

        var updatePlayers = (from p in _dbContext.manchesterUnitedTeams
                             where p.ID == barID
                             select p).SingleOrDefault();

        if (updatePlayers != null)
        {
            updatePlayers.LastName = mLastNameTextBox.Text;
            updatePlayers.FirstName = mFirstNameTextBox.Text;
            updatePlayers.Phone = mCellNumberTextBox.Text;
            updatePlayers.PlayersPosition = mPositionComboBox.Text;
        }
        try
        {
            //Submit to datagridview
            _dbContext.SubmitChanges();

            //Refresh datagridview
            team2DataGridView.RefreshEdit();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //Show an error message
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: **It doesn't work** explains nothing to us. Please provide some more info, what is not working? Is there any error? Any exception? Are your `textboxes` not being populated or `gridview` is not being updated?

Comment: Did you debug the code and verified that `rowIndex` and `barID` are getting the correct values?

Comment: Did you look at Refresh/RefreshEdit ? If not how you declare your context ?

Comment: When I want to select a player from datagridview in tab 2. It does throw an exception as follows   "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:index"

Comment: In debug mode right after step into => "mLastNameTextBox.Text = team2DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();" throws an argument out of range exception

Comment: private void team2DataGridView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Select player from daatagridview
                mLastNameTextBox.Text = team2DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                mFirstNameTextBox.Text = team2DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                mCellNumberTextBox.Text = team2DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
                mPositionComboBox.Text = team2DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[14].Value.ToString();
            }

Answer (score 0):

I think your  dbContext.Submit method  is just not actually submitting the value of the data members of 2 tab . Its just sending the values of your team 1 variables once again